# How do people debug in ECB Emacs?

Tags: emacs, gdb, emacs-ecb

I want to debug in ECB to use its power. I think there is no built in debugging layout for ECB. (Possible useful windows are: stack, breakpoints, locals, threads, gdb command window etc.)

Do I need to create a customized layout in ECB or is there any other way that people use?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there's no ECB-specific solution to that problem is that `M-x gdb` already provides the IDE-like interface that you're looking for (including all the windows you mention).
See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-Graphical-Interface.html for details